# Where to learn metro style app dev. right from the beginning?

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I would like to know the best place to learn microsoft's metro style app dev. and msdn and build windows website prove to be pretty useless, I tried the tutorials there, where the first one was a blog reader and the tutorial is manifested in a poor way.

Answer (score 3):

Get yourself a [Pluralsight OnDemand](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/) subscription and start watching their courses.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.buildwindows.com/ has great links for areas that are constantly adding content.

- Many samples (oficial and by the community) that are on the [App samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/)
- [Getting started with Windows Metro style app development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br211386)  guide at MSDN
- And you can get help on Stackoverflow :) or the [Social Microsoft support site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/category/windowsapps)
- All the [videos of talks](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/BUILD/BUILD2011) presented at //Build conference